# Stylesheet/javascript management rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The application I am writing is pretty complex and has different stylesheets/javascripts depending on the action. Right now I have added some methods to the application controller that allows me to build up an array which then is used in the application.html.erb layout. This feels a little sloppy. It would be nice to somehow configure this from a settings file based on action or something. (I guess that might get messy too though)

Any ideas?

```
def initialize
  super()
  @application_stylesheets = Array.new
  @application_javascripts = Array.new
end

def add_stylesheet(stylesheet)
    @application_stylesheets.push(stylesheet)
end

def add_javascript(javascript)
  @application_javascripts.push(javascript)
end
```

Comment: There's another thing to consider here. In production you'll probably want to minimise the number of requests, so it might be better to combine all your JavaScript and CSS into just two files, in which case it isn't worth coming up with any management scheme.

Comment: javascript_include_tag if controller.controller_name == 'controller' && controller.action_name == 'action'  -- might work?

Comment: I think you are right, I have decided to just include all the javascript/css that I can and turn caching on. This combines the css/js into one file each. If I need to do custom things down the road, I can have the logic in the template file.